# how to get boost json to use the correct data types

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

When I `put_value` using an int, it gets written as a string. Does anyone know how to get it to print as an int?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    ptree node;
    node.put("string", "text here");
    node.put("int", 1);//outputs as "1" and should be 1
    write_json(cout, node, false);//{"string":"text here","int":"1"}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only `int main()` and `int main(int argc, char * argv[])` are standard-conforming.

Comment: @NeilKirk why did you comment this?

Comment: @sehe Because his main isn't standard-conforming?

Comment: @NeilKirk It's clearly irrelevant. If you fear it distracts, consider [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29243662/revisions)ing. Right now you're just ignoring and detracting from a well-posed, fit question.

Comment: @sehe If I just edit it, he might not understand why.

Comment: @NeilKirk That's what I used the edit comment for. Anyhoops. It's noise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The library expressly doesn't support it.

Boost Property Library has not been named "Boost Json Library" because it's not a JSON library. Instead, it's a Property Tree library (that happens to *use* JSON subsets for its purposes).

From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.json_parser):

> The property tree dataset is not typed, and does not support arrays as such. Thus, the following JSON / property tree mapping is used:
>
> - JSON objects are mapped to nodes. Each property is a child node.
> - JSON arrays are mapped to nodes. Each element is a child node with an empty name. If a node has both named and unnamed child nodes, it cannot be mapped to a JSON representation.
> - JSON values are mapped to nodes containing the value. ***However, all type information is lost; numbers, as well as the literals "null", "true" and "false" are simply mapped to their string form.***
> - Property tree nodes containing both child nodes and data cannot be mapped.

And

> JSON round-trips, except for the type information loss.